# How does Base.metadata work in Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Code/Example

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

If I run `print(Base)` then I get result:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base'>
```

(I.e `Base` is a class created by the function `declarative_base`).

If I run `print(Base.metadata)` then I get

```
Metadata(bind=engine(postgres//:user:password@host/database))
```

But exactly how does `print(Base.metadata)` even run if `Base` is a class and `metadata` is an object?

How are the two connected?

I could understand if metadata was a class attribute but from what I understand it is not so how does this work?

Is there something in python syntax that I have missed?

Looking in metadata code:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
metadata = MetaData()
```

What is here the definition of `metadata` and `MetaData`?
Are they both objects?
Is `MetaData()` a function or something else?

According to SQLAlchemy documentation `MetaData` is:

> a container object that keeps together many different features of a database (or multiple databases) being described.

But if it is an object so then how can it be run as something similar to a function: `Metadata()`?

### Summary:

- How are `Base` and `metadata` connected if one is a class and the other is an object?
- How can the command (`Base.metadata`) be run?
- What is the difference between `metadata` and `MetaData` and what is the `MetaData()` definition?

Comment: `Base.metadata` is saying that `metadata` is a property of your `Base` class (which is itself an instance of another class/object). That `metadata` property is an instance of the `MetaData` class/object.

Comment: Great thank you. So Base is then an object/instance and class simultaneously? (I am still trying to get my head around class/instance/objects so thanks for the help)

Comment: @user12288003: everything is an object, so classes are always objects and so are instances. But so are functions, and modules, and so much more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overthinking this. In Python  *everything is an object*. Classes, functions, instances, numbers, strings, lists, dictionaries, modules, ..., ***everything***.

The SQLAlchemy objects you are looking at are no different, there really is nothing special about these.

Yes, the `declarative_base()` function returns a new class object, one you assigned to the name `Base`. That class has attributes, and one of those attributes is named `metadata`. All Python classes have attributes, they can point to any object you like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print(self):
        print(f"Hello, {self.name}!")

class Bar:
    spam = Foo("World")
```

The above class `Bar` has an attribute `spam` that is an instance of the class `Foo`. You can call methods on it:

```
>>> Bar.spam.print()
Hello, World!
```

Note that `Bar` is still a class, and `Bar.spam` is an instance of the `Foo` class:

```
>>> Bar
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Bar.spam
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10d43c650>
>>> type(Bar.spam)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Because `Bar` is just another object, you can also pass it around, put it in a list, or return it from a function. `declarative_base()` constructed a class object for you, with attributes, and returned it to the caller.

Similarly, `Base.metadata` is just an instance of the `MetaData` class:

```
>>> type(Base.metadata)
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.MetaData'>
```

and so is your `metadata = MetaData()` object.

Note that if you **only run `Base = declarative_base()`** and nothing else, the `MetaData` instance is not actually showing any database connection information:

```
>>> Base.metadata
MetaData(bind=None)
```

That's because you didn't actually connect the metadata to a database session. Once you start [connecting a database with an engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#connecting) and start using the models you define by subclassing `Base`, the metadata object at some point will need to know more about the specifics of the database (such as what kind of SQL dialect is supported) and it'll be bound by SQLAlchemy.